# Isomorphism $f$ preserves the order of an element?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

Let's say $f$ is an isomorphism $f:G  \rightarrow G'$, where $G$ and $G'$ are multiplicative groups.

> Then for $x\in G$, if $f(x) = x' \in G'$. Do we have always have $\text{ord}(x) = \text{ord}(x')$? Why?

Comment: Just a side note: $f(x\in G)$ is terrible notation, write something like "$f(x)=x'$, where $x\in G$" instead.

Comment: By $o(x)$, do you mean the order of $x$?

Comment: @user2520938 Ok, thank you !

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Put $y = f(x)$. If $o(x) = n$, then we have $y^n = f(x)^n = f(x^n) = 1$, so that $o(y)\le n$. If $m < n$ and $1 = y^m = f(x)^m = f(x^m)$, then applying $f^{-1}$ to both sides of this equation and noting that isomorphisms send $1\mapsto 1$, we have $1 = x^m$, absurd.

Comment: Nice one ! Thank you ! Just : $f(x)^n = f(x^n)$  is true for every isomorphisme even with non-multiplicative groups ?

Comment: @Littletry Note that every isomorphism is, in particular, a homomorphism, so that $f(ab) = f(a)f(b)$, and by induction $f(x^n) = f(x)^n$. For groups written additively, this equation becomes $f(a+b) = f(a)+f(b)$, and by induction $f(nx) = nf(x)$ where $nx$ means $x + x + \dotsb + x$ ($n$ times).

Comment: Why is that absurd? It seems like you just found a smaller solution to the order, implying that |x|=m for some m < n. I thought you wanted to show m=n by getting a contradiction??

Comment: @JohnD, by definition of $n$, there can be no smaller $m$ such that $x^m=1$. Another way to say it is if $x^m=1$, then by definition of $n$ as the order of $x$, $m\ge n$. This is a contradiction because we started assuming $m<n$.

Answer (score 9):

"Isomorphism" means that the elements of $G$ obtain new names taken from the set $G'$, but  everything operationwise stays the same. It is therefore innate in the very essence of "isomorphism" that the claim you are told to prove is true. Any "formal proof" would make the claim less believable.

Answer (score 2):

More generally, if $f:G  \rightarrow G'$ is a group homomorphism, then $o(f(x))$ divides $o(x)$ simply because $o(x)=m$ implies $e'=f(e)=f(x^m)=f(x)^m$. In particular, $o(f(x)) \le o(x)$.

When $f$ is an isomorphism with inverse $g$, then we get $o(x) = o(gf(x))\le o(f(x)) \le o(x)$ and so $o(f(x)) = o(x)$.

Comment: You show that |f(x)| ≤ |x| twice, you probably meant to say |f(x)| ≥ |x| at some point to conclude they are equal but your proof as it stands is wrong.

Comment: @JohnD, I don't think so. I use that $o(h(z)) \le o(z)$ twice: once for $h=f$ and $z=x$ and once for $h=g$ and $z=f(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  Isomorphisms preserve order.  In fact, any homomorphism $\phi$ will take an element $g$ of order $n$ to an element of order dividing $n$, by the homomorphism property.  Now since an isomorphism has an inverse which is also a homomorphism, the claim follows.  For we get that $n|o(\phi(g))$.

Answer (score 1):

The claim holds also for infinite $\langle g\rangle$. In fact, by the injectivity, $\langle g\rangle\cong f(\langle g\rangle)$; moreover, $f(\langle g\rangle)\le\langle f(g)\rangle$ generally holds for any homomorphism. If $\langle g\rangle$ is infinite, then $\langle g\rangle\cong f(\langle g\rangle) \cong \Bbb Z$, and hence $\langle f(g)\rangle\cong \Bbb Z$. Therefore, $|\langle g\rangle|=|\langle f(g)\rangle|$.