# If two groups are isomorphic, does this imply that they have the same number of elements with the same order?

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism

If two groups are isomorphic, does this imply that they have the same number of elements with the same order? For example, if a group $G$ is isomorphic to a group $H$, and $G$ has $2$ elements of order $3$, I know that $H$ must have element(s) of order $3$, but does it have to be exactly $2$ elements of order $3$?

I am trying to prove that $S_4$ and $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}_3)$ are not isomorphic, and I found that $S_4$ has $9$ elements of order $2$ and $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}_3)$ has only $1$ element of order $2$, but I am not sure if that’s enough to prove that they’re not isomorphic.

Comment: Yes, they do.   So it's enough.

Comment: Do the groups have the same order?

Comment: @Noobie yes, they have the same order.

Comment: Ok.  Then this method should work.

Comment: @EthanBolker yes, your answer in that post is so clear and made it a lot easier to understand! Thanks.

Comment: Also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2353831/11619). As per OP's request I vote to close as a dup of Ethan's suggestion. The result has been mentioned in several earlier threads, but I cannot really recommend one over the other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The group $SL(2,3)$ has center
$$
\{ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 \\\end{pmatrix} \} 
$$
of order $2$, whereas $S_4$ has trivial center. Hence the two groups cannot be isomorphic. This argument
might be easier here than counting the number of elements with a given order.

Comment: Don't we need determinant $1$?

Comment: @Noobie Yes, $\det(A)=2\cdot 2=4=1$, because we are over $\Bbb F_3$. Or $2=-1$ if you prefer.

Comment: Oops.  Nice catch.